# os and closeing a web browser on python with tkinter and webbrowser also inportin

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import os

def scames():
    webbrowser.open("https://www.met.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/fa/fraud/personal-fraud/prevent-personal-fraud/")

def anti():
    webbrowser.open("https://www.avast.com/en-gb/free-antivirus-download#pc")

def mail():
    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
    
def tabs():
    os.system("taskkill /im edge.exe /f")

root = Tk()

root.title("WebBrowsers")

mybutton = Button(root,text = "click me for free v-bucks!!", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = scames)
mybutton.pack()

mybutton2 = Button(root,text = "you have a virus clike here to remove it", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = anti)
mybutton2.pack()

mybutton3 = Button(root,text = "you have mail", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = mail)
mybutton3.pack()

mybutton4 = Button(root,text = "you have to many tabs", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = tabs)
mybutton4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
ERROR: The process "edge.exe" not found.

i have tried this and it not working i am not sure if it edge or Microsoft edge but ether way i get a crash i need to do this with out using pip or downloading stuff as well i want "tabs" to close Microsoft edge as that the browser it opens with for me

Answer (score 0):

The process for Microsoft Edge is called `msedge.exe`, not `edge.exe`.

```
def tabs():
    os.system("taskkill /im msedge.exe /f")
```

To check the name of a process, you need to launch the Task Manager, and then head to the "Details" tab.

Ps. It's a bad practice to import everything from the `tkinter` module if you are only going to use `Tk` and `Button`.